# Adding row number to field in table

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I'm trying to take the output of this query and create a column in my table that will display it:

```
SELECT cons_id, credited_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by cons_id order by cons_id) AS Row_Counter
FROM fy23_jul_aug_anniv_jv;
```

I created a column in my table called COUNTER but cannot seem to be able to figure out how to update it with the output of the above query.  Please help!  Thanks!!

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: which database are you using? and also provide table definition and some sample data

Comment: looks like oracle sql developer, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry...it's sql developer

Comment: IS cons_id, credited_date, UNIQue or have you a primary key in your table?

Comment: cons_id is the primary key

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query:

```
UPDATE <your_tab_to_be_updated>
INNER JOIN (SELECT cons_id, 
                   credited_date,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by cons_id order by cons_id) AS Row_Counter
            FROM fy23_jul_aug_anniv_jv) cte 
        ON <your_tab_to_be_updated>.cons_id       = cte.cons_id
       AND <your_tab_to_be_updated>.credited_date = cte.credited_date
SET <your_tab_to_be_updated>.Row_Counter = cte.Row_Counter;
```

It will join the subquery with your original table on the two other columns that you're selecting in your query, and assign the row_number to your original table.

For more troubleshooting, I can help further if you can share samples from your input tables and corresponding expected output.

Comment: This isn't working.  I just want the row_counter column to be added to my table.  So when I select * from fy23_jul_aug_anniv_jv there is a column that has the counter.

Comment: Read the full answer: "*For more troubleshooting, I can help further if you can share samples from your input tables and corresponding expected output.*"

Comment: Also "*This isn't working.*" does not help understand what problem you are experiencing: describe the error you're getting (if any).